# Show minutes to HH MM SS format in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a value from database in minutes(75) using `LINQ`. Now I want to convert this minutes into HH MM SS format using `LINQ`. Can any one please help me.

Thank you.
I tried with the following code, but I was unsuccessful.

```
TimeSpan tsMinutes;
try
{    
   using (VodafoneDataClassesDataContext vodafoneDataClassesDataContext = new VodafoneDataClassesDataContext())
   {
        vodafoneDataClassesDataContext.Connection.ConnectionString = BECommon.VodafoneConnectionString;
        return (from auditFormsFilledMasters in vodafoneDataClassesDataContext.AuditFormsFilledMasters
        join storeMasters in vodafoneDataClassesDataContext.StoreMasters 
             on auditFormsFilledMasters.StoreId equals storeMasters.Id
        join deskMasters in vodafoneDataClassesDataContext.DeskMasters 
             on auditFormsFilledMasters.DeskId equals deskMasters.Id
        join usersMasters in vodafoneDataClassesDataContext.UserMasters 
             on auditFormsFilledMasters.AuditorId equals usersMasters.Id into tempMaster
        from TempCircleStore in tempMaster.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where auditFormsFilledMasters.StoreId == fieldStoreId
        select new BEAuditFormsFilledMaster
        {
            minutesSpan =  new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt32(auditFormsFilledMasters.LengthofRecordinMin.ToString()), 0),
            tsMinutes = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt32(auditFormsFilledMasters.LengthofRecordinMin.ToString()), 0),
            LengthofConversation = auditFormsFilledMasters.LengthofRecordinMin.ToString(),
            where auditFormsFilledValues.AuditFormsFilledMasterId == auditFormsFilledMasters.Id
            select auditFormsFilledValues.SelectedScore).Sum(),
        }).ToList<BEAuditFormsFilledMaster>().AsReadOnly();
 }
```

Comment: Most of that code seems irrelevant to your question.. where is your DateTime object?

Comment: @Sayse He wants a TimeSpan.

Comment: Ah ok... Im still having a hard time trying to figure out where the problem lies, I presume tsMinutes but never can be sure

Comment: agreed with the above, what is the actual output you are looking to get here?

Comment: I assume it may have to do with this: `minutesSpan =  new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt32(auditFormsFilledMasters.LengthofRecordinMin.ToString()), 0)`

Comment: Does this code compile? From a cursory overview I don't think it would ... your second `where` is missing a `from` statement. Secondly - perhaps you're trying to do too much with the LINQ? Use the LINQ to get the data from the database, and then format the minutes the way you'd like.

Comment: I tried  
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 75, 0);
    string totalTime = ts.Hours + " hours & " + ts.Minutes + " minutes";
    1 hours & 15 minutes

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with linq. You just need to format TimeSpan. I edited your question.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is use the `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` function, and the overloaded `ToString` function:

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(theAmountOfMinutes).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss:")
```

Comment: int tsMinitsts=0;                                                            tsMinutes=  auditFormsFilledMasters.LengthofRecordinMin.ToString(), 
                                LengthofConversation = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(tsMinutes)).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss:"),                                                                  I tried like this but it will show only minutes(17). i want to display the  minutes(17) as 00:17:00 in a label. using LINQ.

Comment: @damodar This should do that.